# Console.Read() until eof

Tags: c#, int, eof

I have to read integers from console sepetating with white characters until end of file, but I don't know how, I search for the answer but I couldn't find it.

```
while((x = Console.Read()) != null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` values are not nullable. You have to use negative one.

```
while((x = Console.Read()) != -1)
```

Comment: You can technically use `int?`, which is nullable.

Comment: but then it is not read until eof just to zero

Comment: @Greg `Console.Read()` returns an `int`

@KingstonJoshua corrected. the returned value is -1 not zero

Comment: read until -1 it's work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Note that the method does not return -1 unless you perform one of the
>   following actions:
>
> - Simultaneously press the Control modifier key and Z console key       (Ctrl+Z), which signals the end-of-file condition.
> - Press an equivalent key that signals the end-of-file condition, such     as the F6 function key in Windows.
> - **Redirect the input stream to a source, such as a text file, that has     an actual end-of-file character.**

[MSDN `Read()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then you can read file by character and calculate each separated value with simple math. It's lazy then will not iterate file to the end immediately for calculating all values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (int i in Read(Console.In))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> Read(TextReader rdr)
{
    int ch;
    bool neg = false;
    int value = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while ((ch = rdr.Read()) != -1)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
        {
            if (count > 0)
                yield return neg ? -value : value;  
            count = 0;
            value = 0;
            neg = false;
        }
        else if (count == 0 && ch == '-')
        {
            neg = true;
        }
        else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            count++;
            value = value*10 + (ch - '0');
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidDataException();
    }

    if (count > 0)
        yield return neg ? -value : value;  
}
```

Comment: I guess that's a bit overkill, LOL.

Comment: @Andrew well it's generic because using TextReader which can be initialized for file and for console. It's lazy and has no overhead as Split method. Also I'm not truly understand source question then I tried to add fully answer.